# Damped oscillation; Induction of a sinusoidal solution in 2nd order ODE through intentional creation of an imaginary number

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling

Sorry for the bad title. I didn't know how to call it.

**1. Motivation.**
To show the motivation of the question more explicitly, I will use an example of damped oscillation which occurs very commonly in physics. From the first equation of the below, we see that the LHS is (elastic force) + (air resistance modelled as being proportional to velocity), and the RHS is the net force according to Newton's second law.

$$\sum F_x = -kx - bv_x = ma_x$$

$$\therefore -kx -b \frac{dx}{dt} = m \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$$

We can make the second equation look better by putting everything to one side and dividing by $m$.

$$x'' + \frac{b}{m} x' + \frac{k}{m} x=0$$

With the ansatz set as $x(t) = e^{\lambda t}$, we get $$\lambda ^2 + \frac{b}{m} \lambda + \frac{k}{m} = 0$$ and therefore

$$\lambda = \frac{-\frac{b}{m} \pm \sqrt{(\frac{b}{m})^2 - 4\frac{k}{m}}}{2} = -\frac{b}{2m} \pm \sqrt{(\frac{b}{2m})^2 - \frac{k}{m}} $$

**2. My speculation.**

I thought the solution will be such as

$$x(t) = e^{-(b/2m)t}(Ae^{\tilde{\omega} t} + Be^{-\tilde{\omega} t})$$, where $A, B$ are arbitrary constants to be determined and $$\tilde{\omega} = \sqrt{(\frac{b}{2m})^2 - \frac{k}{m}}$$

**3. What's in the Textbooks.**

I checked several textbooks, such as Serway, et al., *Physics for Scientists and Engineers* and Kreyszig, et al., *Advanced Engineering Mathematics*, and I found that all of them use another form of the differential equation.

So, they instead defined the $\lambda$ to be as such, intentionally inducing the $i$ in order to allow for a solution in the sinusoidal form through the use of Euler's formula and of the fact that linear combination of solutions is also a solution of an ODE.

$$\lambda = -\frac{b}{2m} \pm \sqrt{(\frac{b}{2m})^2 - \frac{k}{m}} = -\frac{b}{2m} \pm \sqrt{\frac{k}{m} -(\frac{b}{2m})^2 }\ \ i$$

And they used the following form of a solution:

$$x(t) = e^{-(b/2m)t} (A\cos\omega t + B\sin\omega t)$$

where $\omega$ is appropriately defined as $$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m} -(\frac{b}{2m})^2 }$$

Yes, I understand how the identities $\cos \theta = (e^{iwt} + e^{-iwt})/2$ and $\sin \theta = (e^{iwt} - e^{-iwt})/2i$ are used. However, I don't really get how we can say that $$Ae^{\tilde{\omega} t} + Be^{-\tilde{\omega} t}$$

and

$$A\cos\omega t + B\sin\omega t$$

are physically identical. They don't seem to be the models of an identical phenomenon.

Comment: But in Kreyszig, the author gives three cases: 1) Distinct real roots 2) Real double roots 3) Complex roots. So I would say, a sinusoidal solution occurs when the discriminant is negative.

Comment: Think what would happen if you write $\tilde{\omega}=i\omega$. Also note that the constants might be different, so $A$ in the first equation is not the same as $A$ in the second one.